# How to edit HeaderText for TemplateColumn inside DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagrid

I have a client that is requesting that the HeaderText is changed for specific products so that instead of "TL Price/1000 sq ft" it says “TL Price per Pack”.

On the previous page a customer can select multiple categories which will then show multiple tables on this page for the lists of products for those categories. Only certain productId's will need to have their category tables changed.

The problem I run into is to change the headerText the DataGrid has to be rebound, which is done when the repeater is bound. I've tried doing the change 'OnItemDataBound' but still no results.

```html
 <asp:Repeater ID="repProducts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repProducts_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <section class="grey">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h2 class="h1">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TitleImage") %>' visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TitleImage").ToString().Length > 0 %>" alt="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>" />
                                <small visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate").ToString().Length > 0 %>">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate") %>
                                </small>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <p visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InformationLink").ToString().Length > 0 %>">
                                <a target="_blank" href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InformationLink") %>" class="btn btn-block btn-grey"><asp:Literal ID="litProductInformation" runat="server" Text="Product Information" meta:resourcekey="litProductInformationResource2"></asp:Literal> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <p>
                                <button type="button" onclick="downloadPDF([<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductID") %>]);" class="btn btn-block btn-roxul"><asp:Literal ID="litDownloadSingle" runat="server" Text="Download PDF" meta:resourcekey="litDownloadSingleResource1"></asp:Literal> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <asp:DataGrid ID="dgProduct" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductDetails") %>' CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered products" meta:resourcekey="dgProductResource2" OnItemDataBound="dgProduct_ItemDataBound">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText="Item #" meta:resourcekey="colItemNumber"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UPC" HeaderText="UPC Code" meta:resourcekey="colUpcCode"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Stock" HeaderText="Stock" meta:resourcekey="colStock"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Dimensions" HeaderText="Dimensions<br/>Th x W x L" meta:resourcekey="colDimensions"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RValue" HeaderText="R-Value" DataFormatString="{0:n1}" meta:resourcekey="colRValue"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Format" HeaderText="Format" meta:resourcekey="colFormat"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NumberPerPack" HeaderText="No./Pack" meta:resourcekey="colNumberPerPack"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SquareFeetPerPack" HeaderText="SQ FT/<br/>Pack" meta:resourcekey="colSquareFeetPerPack"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PacksPerTrailerLength" HeaderText="Packs/TL" DataFormatString="{0:n0}" meta:resourcekey="colPacksPerTrailerLength"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SquareFeetPerTrailerLength" HeaderText="SQ FT/TL" meta:resourcekey="colSquareFeetPerTrailerLength"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MinimumQuantity" HeaderText="Minimum Order Quantity" meta:resourcekey="colMinQuantity"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="TL Price/<br/>1000 sq ft" meta:resourcekey="colTlPrice">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span class="price<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %></span>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="List Less Discount %" meta:resourcekey="colListLessDiscount">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span class="lessDiscount<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>">0</span>%
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Net Price" meta:resourcekey="colNetPrice">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span class="netPrice<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %></span>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:DataGrid>
                            </div>
                            <div class="visible-sm-block visible-xs-block">
                                <p><small><asp:Literal ID="litAdditionalInfo" runat="server" Text="Additional information can be found by scrolling the table horizontally." meta:resourcekey="litAdditionalInfoResource1"></asp:Literal></small></p>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="discount-label">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litDiscounted" runat="server" Text="List Less Discount %" meta:resourcekey="litDiscountedResource1"></asp:Literal>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="number" class='form-control discount<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>' max="100" min="0">
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" onclick='applyDiscount(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>)' style="padding: 10px 13.5px"><asp:Literal ID="litApplyDiscount" runat="server" Text="Apply Discount" meta:resourcekey="litApplyDiscountResource1"></asp:Literal> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <section class="white">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h2 class="h1">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TitleImage") %>' visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TitleImage").ToString().Length > 0 %>" alt="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>" />
                                <small visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate").ToString().Length > 0 %>">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EffectiveDate") %>
                                </small>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <p visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InformationLink").ToString().Length > 0 %>">
                                <a target="_blank" href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InformationLink") %>" class="btn btn-block btn-grey"><asp:Literal ID="litProductInformation" runat="server" Text="Product Information" meta:resourcekey="litProductInformationResource1"></asp:Literal> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <p>
                                <button type="button" onclick="downloadPDF([<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductID") %>]);" class="btn btn-block btn-roxul"><asp:Literal ID="litDownloadPDF" runat="server" Text="Download PDF" meta:resourcekey="litDownloadPDFResource1"></asp:Literal> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <asp:DataGrid ID="dgProduct" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductDetails") %>' CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered products" meta:resourcekey="dgProductResource1">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="thead" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ItemNumber" HeaderText="Item #" meta:resourcekey="colItemNumber"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="UPC" HeaderText="UPC Code" meta:resourcekey="colUpcCode"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Stock" HeaderText="Stock" meta:resourcekey="colStock"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Dimensions" HeaderText="Dimensions<br/>Th x W x L" meta:resourcekey="colDimensions"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="RValue" HeaderText="R-Value" DataFormatString="{0:n1}" meta:resourcekey="colRValue"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Format" HeaderText="Format" meta:resourcekey="colFormat"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="NumberPerPack" HeaderText="No./Pack" meta:resourcekey="colNumberPerPack"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SquareFeetPerPack" HeaderText="SQ FT/<br/>Pack" meta:resourcekey="colSquareFeetPerPack"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PacksPerTrailerLength" HeaderText="Packs/TL" DataFormatString="{0:n0}" meta:resourcekey="colPacksPerTrailerLength"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="SquareFeetPerTrailerLength" HeaderText="SQ FT/TL" meta:resourcekey="colSquareFeetPerTrailerLength"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="MinimumQuantity" HeaderText="Minimum Order Quantity" meta:resourcekey="colMinQuantity"></asp:BoundColumn>
                                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="TL Price/<br/>1000 sq ft" meta:resourcekey="colTlPrice">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span class="price<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %></span>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="List Less Discount %" meta:resourcekey="colListLessDiscount">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span class="lessDiscount<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>">0</span>%
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Net Price" meta:resourcekey="colNetPrice">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <span class="netPrice<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price") %></span>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:DataGrid>
                            </div>
                            <div class="visible-sm-block visible-xs-block">
                                <p><small><asp:Literal ID="litAdditionalInfo2" runat="server" Text="Additional information can be found by scrolling the table horizontally." meta:resourcekey="litAdditionalInfo2Resource1"></asp:Literal></small></p>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="discount-label">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litDiscounted2" runat="server" Text="List Less Discount %" meta:resourcekey="litDiscounted2Resource1"></asp:Literal>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="number" class='form-control discount<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>' max="100" min="0">
                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" onclick='applyDiscount(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID") %>)' style="padding: 10px 13.5px"><asp:Literal ID="litApplyDiscount2" runat="server" Text="Apply Discount" meta:resourcekey="litApplyDiscount2Resource1"></asp:Literal> <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                int productGroupID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["group"].ToString());
                ProductGroup productGroup = Global.DbContext.ProductGroups.Where(x => x.ProductGroupID == productGroupID).FirstOrDefault();
                string[] tokens = Request.QueryString["products"].Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int[] productIDs = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(tokens, int.Parse);

                switch (this.CurrentLanguage)
                {
                    case "fr":
                        litCount.Text = string.Format("({0}) produits provenant de {1}", productIDs.Count(), productGroup.Name);
                        break;
                    case "es":
                        litCount.Text = string.Format("Para mostrar ({0}) productos provenientes del {1}", productIDs.Count(), productGroup.Name);
                        break;
                    default:
                        litCount.Text = string.Format("Showing ({0}) products from {1}", productIDs.Count(), productGroup.Name);
                        break;
                }

                repProducts.DataSource = Global.DbContext.Products.Where(x => productIDs.Contains(x.ProductID)).ToList();
                repProducts.DataBind();

                foreach (RepeaterItem item in repProducts.Items)
                {
                    DataGrid dgProduct = (DataGrid)item.FindControl("dgProduct");
                    if (dgProduct != null)
                    {
                        for (int col = 0; col < dgProduct.Columns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            if (dgProduct.Columns[col].GetType() == typeof(BoundColumn))
                            {
                                bool has_values = false;

                                foreach (DataGridItem dgitem in dgProduct.Items)
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dgitem.Cells[col].Text) && dgitem.Cells[col].Text != "&nbsp;")
                                        has_values = true;
                                }

                                if (!has_values)
                                {
                                    dgProduct.Columns[col].Visible = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                litError.Text = Utility.FormatErrorMessage(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    protected string AllProductIDs
    {
        get
        {
            return Request.QueryString["products"];
        }
    }
```

I've contemplated using jQuery to access the content since the product id's are passed through the URL but since the template column can't have an ID it means it would be pretty difficult.

If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated. Also first question, be nice if I made a mistake posting. I searched pretty thoroughly.

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this for a while more I was finally able to complete the changes necessary. **OnItemDataBound** worked for me, allowing me to make the changes while the data was in the process of binding.

Each case had to be checked so the label would correctly display the information based on language and based on specific productIDs.

I hope this helps someone later on down the road.

```html
protected void repProducts_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)e.Item.FindControl("dgProduct");
            if (dg != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dg.Columns[i].HeaderText == String.Empty)
                    {
                        if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US")
                        {
                            switch (productIDs[numProductID])
                            {
                                case 264:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Price Per Pack";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                case 266:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Price Per Pack";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                case 296:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Price Per Pack";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Price/<br/>1000 sq ft";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-FR")
                        {
                            switch (productIDs[numProductID])
                            {
                                case 265:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Prix Par Paquet";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                case 267:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Prix Par Paquet";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                case 297:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Prix Par Paquet";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Prix TL/1000<br/>pieds carrés";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "es-ES")
                        {
                            switch (productIDs[numProductID])
                            {
                                case 375:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Precio Por Paquete";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                case 377:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Precio Por Paquete";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                case 405:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "TL Precio Por Paquete";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    dg.Columns[i].HeaderText = "Precio de TL por 1000 pies cuadrados";
                                    dg.DataBind();
                                    numProductID++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            litError.Text = Utility.FormatErrorMessage(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you used a repeater to show the products. Too bad you used DataGrid for the ProductDetails. That one could have been a repeater too, which gives you more control. Anyway, you are close imo. I think you have todo the following (doing this by head and it's been like 10 years at least since I used DataGrid/GridView)

```
protected void dgProduct_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args) {
    if (args.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) {
        //Adjust the headerText here
        args.Row.Cells[3].Text = "New header text";
        //Or more elegantly try to avoid doing this by index
    }
}
```

Another tip for the repeater where you can avoid double coding for ItemTemplate and AlternatingItemTemplate if it's basically just different background colors. Use an ItemTemplate only and use the following to set css-classes for alternating, so you can set the different backgroundcolor in css.

```
<section class='<%# (Container.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ? "grey" : "white" %>'>
```